# Imprimir un árbol binario en Java

Tags: java

tengo la clase prueba pero me marca errores ya tengo mis clases definidas; en mi clase prueba debo insertar los numeros 10,9,...,2,1,0,...,-5(en ese orden) en el arbol binario de busqueda y arbolAVL e imprimirlos. 
Hacer los recorridos (ya los tengo definidos) de ambos arboles

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
package arboles;

/**
 * @param <E>
 */

public class ArbolBinario<E>{

    protected Nodo<E> raiz;

    public ArbolBinario (Nodo <E> raiz){
        this.raiz = raiz;
    }

    public void visitar (Nodo<E> raiz){
        System.out.println(raiz.getElemento() + ";");
    }

    public void recorrerPreorden (){
        recorrerPreorden(this.raiz);
    }
    public void recorrerPreorden(Nodo <E> nodo){
        if (nodo != null){
            visitar (nodo);
            recorrerPreorden(nodo.getIzquierdo());
            recorrerPreorden(nodo.getDerecho());
        }
    }

    public void recorrerPostorden (){
        recorrerPreorden(this.raiz);
    }
    public void recorrerPostorden(Nodo <E> nodo){
        if (nodo != null){
            visitar (nodo);
            recorrerPostorden(nodo.getIzquierdo());
            recorrerPostorden(nodo.getDerecho());
        }
    }

    public void recorrerInOrden (){
        recorrerPreorden(this.raiz);
    }
    public void recorrerInOrden(Nodo <E> nodo){
        if (nodo != null){
            visitar (nodo);
            recorrerInOrden(nodo.getIzquierdo());
            recorrerInOrden(nodo.getDerecho());
        }
    }

     @Override
    public String toString() {
        return crearRepresentacion(raiz, "", "", false);
    }

    private String crearRepresentacion(Nodo<E> nodo, String representacion, 
            String nivel, boolean esIzquierdo) {

        representacion += nivel;

        if (!nivel.equals("")) {
            representacion += "\b\b" + (esIzquierdo ? "\u251C": "\u2514") + "\u2500";
        }

        if(nodo == null)
            return representacion += "\n";

        representacion += nodo + "\n";

        // Hijo izquierdo
        representacion = crearRepresentacion(nodo.getIzquierdo(), representacion, nivel + "\u2502 ", true);
        // Hijo derecho
        representacion = crearRepresentacion(nodo.getDerecho(), representacion, nivel + "  ", false);

        return representacion;
    }

}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    package arboles;
    /**
     *
     *
     * @param <E>
     */
    public class ArbolBinarioBusqueda <E extends Comparable<E>> extends ArbolBinario<E>{

    private Nodo<E> raiz; 
    private int cantidad;

       Nodo llamada = new Nodo();


        public ArbolBinarioBusqueda(Nodo<E> raiz) {
            super(raiz);
        }

         public void ArbolBinario()
        {
            this.cantidad=0;
        }

        public int getCantidad()
        {
            return cantidad;
        }

        public Elemento<E> getRaiz()
        {
            return raiz;
        }

         private Nodo<E> validar(Elemento<E> elemento)
        {
            if(!(elemento instanceof Nodo))
            {
            return null;
            }
            Nodo<E> nodoBinario = (Nodo<E>)elemento;
            return nodoBinario.getPadre()==nodoBinario ?null:nodoBinario;
        }

         public void poner (Nodo<E> n, E elemento){
             if(n != null){
                 if (n.elemento.compareTo(elemento) > 0){
                     if (n.izquierdo != null);
                     insertar (n.izquierdo, elemento);
                 }else{
                     n.izquierdo = new Nodo <> (elemento);
                 }
             }
             if (n.elemento.compareTo(elemento) < 0){
                 if (n.derecho != null){
                     insertar (n.derecho, elemento);
                 }else{
                     n.derecho = new Nodo <> (elemento);
                 }
             }
         }


         public void insertar (Nodo<E> n , E elemento){
             if (raiz == null){
                 raiz = new Nodo <> (elemento);
             }
             if (raiz.elemento.compareTo(elemento) < 0){
                 if (raiz.derecho != null){
                     poner (raiz.derecho, elemento);
                 }else{
                     raiz.derecho = new Nodo <> (elemento);
                 }
             }
             if (raiz.elemento.compareTo(elemento) > 0){
                 if (raiz.izquierdo != null){
                     poner (raiz.izquierdo, elemento);
                 }else{
                     raiz.izquierdo = new Nodo <> (elemento);
                 }
             }
             if (raiz.elemento.compareTo(elemento) == 0){
                 return ;
             }
         }


    }
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
package arboles;

/**
 *
 * @param <E>
 */
public interface Elemento<E>
{
    E getElemento();
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------



package arboles;

/**
 * @param <E>
 */
public class Nodo<E> implements Elemento<E> {
    private int h;
    E elemento;
    private Nodo<E>padre;
    protected Nodo<E>izquierdo;
    protected Nodo<E>derecho;

    public Nodo(E elemento){
        this.elemento = elemento;
    }

    public Nodo(){
        this.h= Math.max(izquierdo.h, derecho.h) + 1;
    }

    public int getH(){
        return h;
    }

    public void setH(int h){
        this.h = h;
    }

    public int h (Nodo <E> nodo){
        if (nodo == null || (nodo.getDerecho() == null && nodo.getIzquierdo() == null))
            return 0;
    return nodo.getH();
    }

    public Nodo(E elemento, Nodo<E> padre, Nodo<E> izquierdo, Nodo<E> derecho) {
        this.elemento = elemento;
        this.padre = padre;
        this.izquierdo = izquierdo;
        this.derecho = derecho;
    }

    @Override
    public E getElemento(){
        return elemento;
    }

    public void setElemento(E elemento){
        this.elemento = elemento;
    }

    public Nodo<E> getPadre(){
        return padre;
    }

    public void setPadre(Nodo<E> padre){
        this.padre = padre;
    }

    public Nodo<E> getIzquierdo(){
        return izquierdo;
    }

    public void setIzquierdo(Nodo<E> Izquierdo){
        this.izquierdo = Izquierdo;
    }

    public Nodo<E> getDerecho(){
        return derecho;
    }

    public void setDerecho(Nodo<E> Derecho){
        this.derecho = Derecho;
    }

}
```

### }

package arboles;

```
public class ArbolAVL<E extends Comparable<E>> extends ArbolBinario<E> {

    public ArbolAVL(NodoAVL<E> nodo) {
        super(nodo);
    }

    private NodoAVL<E> raiz;

    public void insertar(E elemento){
        this.raiz = raiz;
    }

    private NodoAVL<E> organizar(NodoAVL<E> nodo, int altIzquierda, int altDerecha){
 if(obtenerFactorEquilibrio(nodo)==2){
  if( obtenerFactorEquilibrio(nodo.getDerecha() )==1  || obtenerFactorEquilibrio(nodo.getDerecha()) == 0){
   nodo = rotacionSimpleIzquierda(nodo);
  }

  else if(obtenerFactorEquilibrio(nodo.getDerecha() )==-1){
   nodo = rotacionDobleDerechaIzquierda(nodo);
  }
 }
 else if(obtenerFactorEquilibrio(nodo)==-2){
  if(obtenerFactorEquilibrio(nodo.getIzquierda() )==-1 || obtenerFactorEquilibrio(nodo.getDerecha())==0){
   nodo = rotacionSimpleDerecha(nodo);
  }

  else if(obtenerFactorEquilibrio(nodo.getIzquierda())==1){
   nodo = rotacionDobleIzquierdaDerecha(nodo);
  }
 }

 return nodo;
    }


    //Obtiene el factor de equilibrio del nodo proporcionado por lel parametro
    public int obtenerFactorEquilibrio(NodoAVL<E> nodo){
     if(nodo!=null){
      return nodo.getFactorE();
     }else{
      return 0;
     }
    }

 //Metodo para realizar una rotacion simple hacia la izquierda con el subarbol
    public NodoAVL<E> rotacionSimpleIzquierda(NodoAVL<E> nodo){
 NodoAVL<E> auxiliar = nodo;

     nodo = auxiliar.getDerecha(); 
 auxiliar.setDerecha(nodo.getIzquierda());

 nodo.setIzquierda(auxiliar);

 return nodo;
    }

//Metodo para realizar una rotacion simple hacia la derecha en el subarbol    
    public NodoAVL<E> rotacionSimpleDerecha(NodoAVL<E> nodo){
     NodoAVL<E> auxiliar = nodo;
     nodo = auxiliar.getIzquierda();

 auxiliar.setIzquierda(nodo.getDerecha());
 nodo.setDerecha(auxiliar);

 return nodo;
    }

//Metodo para realizar una doble rotacion (Izquierda/Derecha)    
    public NodoAVL<E> rotacionDobleIzquierdaDerecha(NodoAVL<E> nodo){
     NodoAVL<E> auxiliar = nodo;

        auxiliar= rotacionSimpleIzquierda(auxiliar.getIzquierda());

 nodo.setIzquierda(auxiliar);

 auxiliar = rotacionSimpleDerecha(nodo);

 return auxiliar;
    }

//Metodo para realizar una doble rotacion (Derecha/Izquierda    
    public NodoAVL<E> rotacionDobleDerechaIzquierda(NodoAVL<E> nodo){
     NodoAVL<E> aux = nodo;

        aux = rotacionSimpleDerecha(aux.getDerecha());

 nodo.setDerecha(aux);

 aux= rotacionSimpleIzquierda(nodo);

 return aux;
    }

//Metodo que determina si elarbol o subarbol esta equilibrado
public int equilibrado(NodoAVL<E> n){
 int hIzquierda = 0;
 int hDerecha = 0;

 if(n==null){
      return 0;
     }

     hIzquierda = equilibrado(n.getIzquierda());

     if(hIzquierda < 0){
      return hIzquierda;
     }

     hDerecha = equilibrado(n.getDerecha());

     if(hDerecha <0){
      return hDerecha;
     }

     //Condicion para el caso en el que no esta equilibrado
     if(Math.abs(hIzquierda - hDerecha)>1){
      return -1;
     }

     //Si el fragmento del arbol es AVL devolvemos la altura
     return Math.max(hIzquierda, hDerecha) + 1;
}
```

### }

package arboles;

```
/**
 *
 * @param <E>
 */

public class NodoAVL <E extends Comparable <E>> extends Nodo<E>{
    private int factorEquilibrio;

 //Se crea un contructor por defecto
 public NodoAVL(){
  dato = null;
  izquierda = null;
  derecha = null;
  factorEquilibrio = 0;
 }    
    public NodoAVL (NodoAVL<E> nodo){
        this.nodo = nodo;
    }
    protected NodoAVL<E> nodo;

 public int getFactorE(){
  int alturaDerecha = 0;
  int alturaIzquierda = 0;
  if(this.getDerecha()!=null){
      alturaDerecha = this.getDerecha().getAltura();
     }
     if(this.getIzquierda()!=null){      
      alturaIzquierda = this.getIzquierda().getAltura();
     }
  return (alturaDerecha - alturaIzquierda);
 }

 //Se asigna un valor al factor de equilibrio
 public void setFactorE(int factorEquilibrio){
  this.factorEquilibrio = factorEquilibrio;
 }

 private E dato;

 private NodoAVL<E> izquierda;

 private NodoAVL<E> derecha;


 public NodoAVL(E dato){
  this.dato = dato;
  izquierda = null;
  derecha = null;
  factorEquilibrio = 0;
 }    


 //Devuelve el nodo a la izquierda del actual
 public NodoAVL<E> getIzquierda(){
  return izquierda;
 }

 //Devuelve el nodo a la derecha del actual
 public NodoAVL<E> getDerecha(){
  return derecha;
 }


 //Devuelve el dato contenido en el nodo 
 public E getDato(){
  return dato;
 }

 //Asigna un nodo al hijo derecho del nodo
 public void setDerecha(NodoAVL<E> derecha){
  this.derecha = derecha;
 }


 //Asigna un nodo al hijo izquierdo del nodo.
 public void setIzquierda(NodoAVL<E> izquierda){
  this.izquierda = izquierda;
 }


 //Asigna un dato al nodo
 public void setDato(E dato){
  this.dato = dato;
 }

//Se define un entero para la altura
 public int getAltura(){

  int hIzquierda = 0;
  int hDerecha = 0;

  if(this.getDato()==null){
    return 0;
     }

  if(this.getIzquierda()!=null){
   hIzquierda = this.getIzquierda().getAltura();
  }else{
    return hIzquierda;
  }

     if(this.getDerecha()!=null){  
      hDerecha = this.getDerecha().getAltura();
     }else{
      return hDerecha;
     }
     return Math.max(hIzquierda, hDerecha) + 1;
 }

}
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
package arboles;

public class Prueba {

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

      Nodo<Integer> raiz= new Nodo<>( 
            new Nodo<>(new Nodo<>(new Nodo<>(1),2,new Nodo<>(11)),
                10,
                new Nodo<>(new Nodo<>(13),14,null)),
            3,
            new Nodo<>(new Nodo<>(8),20,null)
      );
        ArbolBinario<Integer> arbol=new ArbolBinario<>(raiz);
        System.out.print(arbol);
              }
}
```

Mi impresion tendria que ser asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: Si tiene mensajes de errores, por favor agregarlos en la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Por qué agregas esas diagonales a tu pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que le estás especificando que tipo de `Nodo` y `ArbolBinario` es, y te da ese fallo. Para solucionarlo debes de indicar en el `constructor` que tipo de Nodo es entre las `<>`, en este caso sería `<Integer>`:

```
public class Prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Nodo<Integer> raiz = new Nodo<Integer>(
                new Nodo<Integer>(new Nodo<Integer>(new Nodo(1), 2, new Nodo<Integer>(11)), 10, new Nodo<Integer>(new Nodo<Integer>(13), 14, null)), 3,
                new Nodo<Integer>(new Nodo<Integer>(8), 20, null));
        ArbolBinario<Integer> arbol = new ArbolBinario<>(raiz);
        System.out.print(arbol);

    }}
```

Comment: Hola, realice lo que comentas pero me continua marcando errores. Gracias por comentar mi duda

Comment: Hola, que errores te marca ahora? El error original, de que no puede inferir el tipo de parametro no es, no?

Comment: Me parece que no. Creo que esta mal como definí mi clase prueba en si